# Redshift not recognizing quoted field?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Here is my Redshift `COPY` command:

```
COPY {table}
                FROM '{copy_from}'
                CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id={pub};aws_secret_access_key={priv}'
                DELIMITER '|'
                GZIP
                TRIMBLANKS
                TRUNCATECOLUMNS
                ACCEPTINVCHARS
                TIMEFORMAT 'auto'
                DATEFORMAT 'auto'
```

The output from `Postgresql` will have quoted fields that contain the delimiter, but `Redshift` is treating it as two seperate fields.

So for example, the field `CG | EG` would output from `Postgres` as `"CG | EG"`, and then Redshift tries to split on it.  Is there a way to specify to recognize quoted fields in my `COPY`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add "CSV" mode into your COPY command. Pipe delimiter should stay.

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/tutorial-loading-run-copy.html#tutorial-loading-csv-format